# API in laravel with post method

Tags: php, laravel

when i hit api with post method the result this:
please tell me what is problem here

[image: strong text]

[[image: controller]]

[[image: form]]

Comment: This happens commonly when the CSRF token is missing from the request.

Comment: yah i know that but this is not missing in the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is CSRF token issue. If you want to except CSRF token on particular route then you can go on **/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php**

Write your route name in $except array.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'login', 'webservice'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that is the **CSRF token** issue. if you want to run api in post method then you want to except **CSRF token** for api.

Remove csrf token:-
goto **/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php** and write your route name in **$except** array.

like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'login', 'api'
    ];
}
```

that will be work definitely.. :)

Comment: This answer was already given by Dwarkesh Soni.

Answer (score 0):

**this also work**

```
app > Http > Kernel.php

and comment the same line as I did:

/**
  * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
  *
  * @var array
  */
  protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
   //   \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
  ];
```

Comment: This is not proper way to do this. If you comment this line then CSRF token will be removed for whole routes so don't do that.